# Retrieving all lost HTML files from Angular dist folder

Tags: angular

I have no idea how this happened, but somehow, I lost all my HTML files from my Angular project some time after I created a `dist` folder (`ng build`) and pushed it to my EC2 server. Is there any way to get the contents from the `dist` folder on the server back into the project?

Comment: is rebuilding not an option?

Comment: Just run ng build again

Comment: I get this error : `Error: Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" from [directory]`

Comment: What do you mean by you "lost all your HTML files?" After you do a build (`ng build`) the only HTML file you will  have in your `dist` directory is the `index.html`. Is your `index.html` file not present in your `dist` directory?

Comment: They're not present at all in `src`. Somehow they all got wiped from my machine!

Comment: So you lost your sources and you didnt backup nor pushed code to VCS? Well you got a problem nom my friend.

Comment: Pretty much. The HTML on the Github repo is outdated (I should have been pushing everyday!) but all the other files are still there

Comment: If you built your project with AOT then your templates are gone. AOT will convert the HTML for components into JavaScript and add that to the bundles. There isn't any HTML sources inside your `dist` folder on the production server. If you had AOT turned off, then they might be there. You'll have to inspect the contents to see where they are.

Comment: Luckily, I didn't!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue, manually.

**What I did**

I learned that `index.html` is located in `dist/index.html`. From there, it was simply copy, paste, and remove the row of `<script>` tags.

The other HTML files were more tedious. I had to `Ctrl+F` for their names, in `dist/main.js`, go to the `module.exports` line in the anonymous function right after, copy the whole string (it's literally the entire file's contents on one line), paste it into a new file of that filename created where it was, and replace literal `\\n`,`\\r\\n` with actual newline character (enable regular expansions in the find-and-replace feature of your text editor), and escaped `\"` with actual `"`.

I did have to find and manually revive some CSS and TypeScript files, but it was done the same way (the TypeScript can be found within that extremely long line in `dist/main.js.map`, although you have to **really** know what you're looking for, and the patience/persistence to find it. Luckily, there were only a few lines of TypeScript I was missing.)

I'm lucky this project is nascent.

Comment: /* I made sure to, right after all this, verify that the project worked, and then pushed to GitHub repository right away */

Answer (score 0):

In a MEAN app, I created a client folder in the root directory, then copied and pasted the dist folder there.
Don't forget to change your static path in your server file:

> app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/client/dist/pet-shelter')); //
>   moving dist to client folder

Let me know what solution you came up with? Mine seems primitive.

Comment: How does that answer the question?